# Credentials Java application connect to google cloud datastore

Tags: java, gcloud, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a local java application which is to access my google datastore. I followed the tutorial here http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.0/index.html

This is my basic code

```
package myproject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.cloud.AuthCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.Key;
import com.google.cloud.datastore.KeyFactory;

public class Main {
    private String projID = "myID";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("correct");
        Main test = new Main();
        Datastore dstore = test.getDatastore();
        KeyFactory keyFactory = dstore.newKeyFactory().kind("keyKind");
        Key key = keyFactory.newKey("keyName");
        Entity entity = Entity.builder(key)
            .set("name", "John Doe")
            .set("age", 30)
            .build();
        dstore.put(entity);

    }

    private Datastore getDatastore() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("./resource/mycredential.json");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                    + fis.available());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.builder()
                  .projectId(projID)
                  .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(fis)).build();
        Datastore datastore = options.service();
        return datastore;
    }
}
```

I created the json credential key from cloud console. After I run the program, it shows com.google.datastore.v1beta3.client.DatastoreFactory makeClient
??: Not using any credentials

I am really trapped here. How to create the right credential and use it correctly? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "INFO" message which means nothing. I agree that it's confusing, but this message shows up every time I start my local program, which works fine - connects to the Datastore, retrieves and saves data, etc.

Comment: What does the "INFO" message mean? Yes I checked the cloud console, the entity is already there.

Comment: The message is quite confusing and is going away in a future release. This message comes from the library underneath gcloud-java which sets up the connection to Datastore. gcloud-java manually attaches permissions to outgoing HTTP requests, so when the library creates a connection it thinks no credential was provided.

Comment: How can I get rid of this message. I would like to show some useful information on my screen. And this info appear every time. It really block the useful info.